# How to hide cookie path in https response

Tags: security, webserver, session-cookies

[Click Here for screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfokF.png)

How can I hide cookie path in http response.
As shown in screenshot, it is showing real path of 'abc' cookie i.e. '/opt/tmp/', but I do not want to show it on browser response.

I am using PHP code.

Please let me know what settings I need to do.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to restrict the domain and path attributes like below for cookies in java.

If a cookie is required to be accessed from only `abc.stackoverflow.com` and the subfolders of the root path `/service/test` of the domain, do as follows:

```
cookie.setDomain ("abc.stackoverflow.com");
cookie.setPath("/service/test");
```

Comment: Hi Ameen,
Thanks for update.
But I am using PHP.
And i have set session path in php.ini

Comment: Apologies Avinash. I din't concentrate on the php part of your question. As soon as I saw cookies, I jumped into my favourite programming language Java. Btw, php also has a equivalent setcookie function with path attribute. Below link for your reference (which you might already know) https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp